# Visual Studio SSDT Unresolved reference to SSISDB

Tags: ssdt

I have a stored procedure in Visual Studio SSDT Project which use SSISDB database. And I get a warnings like "unresolved reference to SSISDB". I tried to create a new reference but I can only select "master" or "msdb" database. Any ideas how to repair this reference to SSISDB issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have done is create a new SSDT project, then import SSISDB and create a dacpac that can then be referenced in other projects.